# App crashes and restarts phone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm beta testing an app, and on most devices it works fine. But I found at least one device (iphone 6s, but I have other of that working fine), it's not the app that crashes, the whole telephone just restarts.
Nothing to find in the logs and no clue where in the app this is caused.

How is this even possible?
Where to start looking?

Comment: The answer to this question might also answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824004/can-my-ipad-app-cause-the-device-to-reboot

Comment: Any specific error message thrown? Maybe also see if `didRecieveMemoryWarning` is being called at all and check memory usage in the debugger. Using too much memory can cause the phone to hard reboot.

Comment: Never more the 110 MB. And only for a short time. Most time the app is between 30 and 50 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end it was a kind of memory problem. But not because waisting the whole system memory.
It was a simple recursion. In some cases it missed the breaking condition. Did not consume noticeable cpu or much RAM, but a very fast stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem, an app crash that totally reboot my iPhone. I discovered what was with this workaround:

1. Connect your device to your Mac
2. Open Xcode --> Window --> Devices
3. Select on the left your device
4. Clean on the bottom the log
5. Redo the same steps for crash the app
6. See what happens on the log

For more clarity, you should have this window:

[image]

You probably see a lot of lines but with a little patience you should see what it's the problem, or just see the area problem at least.

I hope this helps!